# Is there a SafeState equivalent in neovim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I have the following function that I'm porting to neovim:

```
" ---------------
" Auto record visual mode
" ---------------
" Allows executing operators with a different syntax.
" First we go to visual mode and we can select with the target-objects the text
" we wan to work on. Then we execute the operation. Finally we can repeat this
" with gv (goto visual, repeat visual)
nmap gv v@v

let s:last_mode = 'n'
augroup visual_enter_normal_enter
    au!
    au SafeState * call s:fire_visual_enter_normal_enter()
augroup END

fu! s:fire_visual_enter_normal_enter() abort
    let mode = mode()
    if s:last_mode is# 'n'
    \ && index(['v', 'V', "\<c-v>"], mode) != -1
    \ && exists('#User#VisualEnter')
        do <nomodeline> User VisualEnter
    elseif s:last_mode isnot# 'n'
    \ && mode() is# 'n'
    \ && exists('#User#NormalEnter')
        do <nomodeline> User NormalEnter
    endif
    let s:last_mode = mode
endfu

augroup record_keys_in_visual_mode
    au!
    au User VisualEnter call s:recording_start()
    au User NormalEnter call s:recording_stop()
augroup END

fu! s:recording_start() abort
    if reg_recording() is# ''
        call feedkeys('qv', 'int')
    endif
endfu

fu! s:recording_stop() abort
    if reg_recording() is# 'v' && mode() is# 'n'
        call feedkeys('q', 'int')
    endif
endfu
```

Nevertheless I get:

```
E216: No such group or event: SafeState * call s:fire_visual_enter_normal_enter()
```

Is there an equivalent of `SafeState` in neovim?

Comment: `SafeState` is relatively recent to vim: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8aeec40207b5adcd3a155277dc4f29189343b963 I wouldn't expect nvim to have it, but you can ask their github or their help files

Comment: If you need the `SafeState` event, your best bet is to use Vim.

Comment: neovim is working way more smoother unfortunately, so I think I'll stay for a while with it and leave that function behind. Good to know though, I'll check in the future if they have included it